# Passing custom object through method channel flutter

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, flutter

I am trying to pass a custom object which is of type `User` from native platform to Flutter. The `User` class is part of a library and not accessible directly for editing. Here is my android and iOS code implementation for the same. Problem is I am not able to find a solution on how to pass this object through method channels in such a way that I can parse it in the Dart code easily.

**Android part**:

```
private fun loginUser(uid: String, apiKey: String, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        MyChat.login(uid, apiKey, object : MyChat.CallbackListener<User>() {
            override fun onSuccess(user: User) {
                Log.e(TAG, user.toString())
                result.success(hashMapOf("RESULT" to true, "AVATAR" to user.avatar,
                        "CREDITS" to user.credits,
                        "EMAIL" to user.email,
                        "LAST_ACTIVE" to user.lastActiveAt,
                        "NAME" to user.name,
                        "ROLE" to user.role,
                        "STATUS" to user.status,
                        "STATUS_MESSAGE" to user.statusMessage).toString())
            }

            override fun onError(p0: MyChatException?) {
                Log.e(TAG, p0?.message)
                result.error("FAILED", "Unable to create login", null)
            }
        })
    }
```

**iOS implementation**:

```
func loginUser(result: @escaping FlutterResult, uid: String, apiKey: String){
        MyChat.login(UID: uid, apiKey: apiKey, onSuccess: { (user) in
            // Login Successful
            let data: [String: Any] = ["RESULT":true,
                                       "AVATAR":user.avatar!,
                                       "CREDITS": user.credits,
                                       "EMAIL": user.email!,
                                       "LAST_ACTIVE":String(user.lastActiveAt),
                                       "NAME":user.name!,
                                       "ROLE":user.role!,
                                       "STATUS":user.status.rawValue,
                                       "STATUS_MESSAGE":user.statusMessage]
            let jsonData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [.prettyPrinted])
            result(String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .ascii))
        }) { (error) in
            // Login error
            result(FlutterError(code: "FAILED", message:"Login failed with exception: " + error.errorDescription, details: nil))

        }
    }
```

**My dart code**:

```
    Future<String> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    String status = "";
    try {
      final String result = await platform
          .invokeMethod('loginUser', {"UID": UID, "API_KEY": API_KEY});
      print(result); //How to parse?
    status = "Hello";
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Exception");
      status = e.message;
    }
    return status;
  }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass data in hash map.

**In Android:**

```
result.success(hashMapOf(
    "CREDITS" to user.credits,
    "EMAIL" to user.email,
    ...
))
```

**In iOS:**

```
let data: [String: Any] = [...]
result(data)
```

**In Flutter:**

```
final result = await platform.invokeMethod<Map<String, dynamic>>('loginUser', ...);
final credits = result['CREDITS'] as String;
final email = result['EMAIL'] as String;
...
```

Comment: Does it mean we can't return custom objects?

Comment: I need to send a file object from the flutter app to the iOS native app, I can get the value as dictionary after that which type I need to downcast from any object in swift?

Comment: @Vinoth consider passing path to file as `String`

Comment: Yeah thanks, @Pavel. Currently, I'm sending the file path only. But we can also send bytes to native iOS and in the appdelegate, we can get it like `let data: FlutterStandardTypedData = call.arguments as! FlutterStandardTypedData`

Answer (score 1):

you can use invokeMapMethod which is an implementation of invokeMethod that can return typed maps.
like this :

```
final result = await platform.invokeMapMethod('loginUser', ...);
```

**or you can pass json object as string like that :**

**in android**

```
platform.success(
    "{\"CREDITS\":\"${user.credits}\",\"EMAIL\":\"${user.email}\",\"LAST_ACTIVE\":\"${user.lastActiveAt}\"}"
)
```

**in flutter**

```
var result = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('loginUser' , '');
var json = json.decode(result);

var credit = json['CREDITS'];
var email = json['EMAIL'];
var lastActive = json['LAST_ACTIVE'];
```