# How to pass a Custom POJO or DTO object from flutter to Android using method channel?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I have searched into this topic a lot!! but couldn't find any proper answer ?

Similar kind of answer has been provided in this question [Passing custom object through method channel flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900977/passing-custom-object-through-method-channel-flutter/55903211)

but answers are of no help .

If anyone could tell the proper way to pass custom object like USER or EMPLOYEE from flutter to android and back from android to flutter that would serve my purpose .

Thanks.

Comment: do you want Android objects data as Flutter model object?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, and thank Google it is not possible, the more abstract data is the more portable it gets.

You have to Serialize your objects and deserialize inside your native code (Kotlin/Java/Objective-C/Swift)

Using Map or bytes or String or generic List, etc

Everything about platform channel data types is explained [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

[image]